# Protect Local Administrator accounts

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, password-management

We are setting up an Active Directory for our server room (Windows Servers + Linux Servers).

Our local Administrator accounts should remain active in case of an emergency.

However to avoid our employees to keep using the local Administrator accounts we want to change all the local Administrator's passwords and keep them in a secured space, maybe even have the ability to create single sign ons in case someone needs one time access.

What would be the best practice to deal with this kind of situation? Does something like this exists within AD or would we have to look for an extra platform?

Comment: [Microsoft LAPS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/mt227395.aspx). Haven't tried it but should be what you're looking for?

Comment: @Seth this looks very promising. Will definitely look into this.